# How extract value from a json object using javascript

Tags: php, json

Following is my json object produced using php script

```
$to_encode[]= mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo json_encode($to_encode);
```

and the output is

```
[{"wid":"2","repid":"1"}]
```

to extract values of `wid` and `repid` I used below given code in js

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);

var a = obj.["wid"];
var b = obj.["repid"];
```

but I'm getting value for `a` and `b` as  `undefined` instead of `2`,`1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your JSON encodes not simply one object, but an array containing one object. But that array doesn't have the `wid` and `repid` properties, only the object inside the array has!

Try

- `{"wid":"2","repid":"1"}` to encode just an object without putting it into an array *or*
- `obj[0]["wid"]` to access the properties of the first (and only) object in the array.

By the way, if you know the names of the properties, you should use dot notation: `obj[0].wid` instead of `obj[0]["wid"]`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your json object is actually an array of objects (in this case there only is one object: `{"wid":"2","repid":"1"}`).

This should work

```js
var obj = data[0] //access the first element of the json array
var a   = obj.wid;
var b   = obj.repid;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `obj[wid]`. Array have `wid` as key and `2` as a value.

Comment: `obj[wid]` showing error i.e `Uncaught ReferenceError: wid is not defined`