# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wsname' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get values from database using following code (*login.js*)

```
$.post("http://awebsite.com/app/login.php",{ rep1: rep, password1:password},
function(data) {
if(data=='Invalid rep.......') {
$('input[type="text"]').css({"border":"2px solid red","box-shadow":"0 0 3px red"});
$('input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid #00F5FF","box-shadow":"0 0 5px #00F5FF"});
alert(data);
}else if(data=='Repname or Password is wrong...!!!!'){
$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid red","box-shadow":"0 0 3px red"});
alert(data);
} else if(data !==''){
//$("form")[0].reset();
//$('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid #00F5FF","box-shadow":"0 0 5px #00F5FF"});
//alert(data);
alert("Welcome " + rep + "  !!");

var obj = JSON.parse(data);

//[{"wid":"2","repid":"1"}]
 //objwid = obj[0]["wid"];
 //objrepid = obj[0]["repid"];
 objwsname= obj[0]["wsname"];
```

but I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wsname' of undefined` error in this line `objwsname= obj[0]["wsname"];`

I'm sure that getting correct data see this 
[image]

Am using following scripts in html

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2-min.js"></script>
<script src="src\jquery.tabletojson.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
```

Comment: [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be just this:

```
objwsname = obj.wsname;
```

obj is an object not an array.

If the `JSON` string that is passed to `JSON.parse` contains an array, then it will return an array. In your case, a string containing a `JSON` object was passed to `JSON.parse` - so it returned an object.

Comment: I just wonder sudden what happend,I used that way  because of the answer provided in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985949/how-extract-value-from-a-json-object-using-javascript).

Comment: It depends on what the `JSON` is. In that question you mention - they are referencing `JSON` that is an array of objects. In your case, you are working with an object - not an array. If the `JSON` string that is passed to `JSON.parse` contains an array, then it will return an array. In your case, a string containing a JSON object was passed to `JSON.parse` - so it returned an object.

Answer (score 1):

As this is just an object not an array which holds one or more objects, so you don't need to provide the index *`[0]`*:

```
objwsname = obj["wsname"];
```

or:

```
objwsname = obj.wsname;
```

can be done to get the `wsname`.

---

See if you have an array which holds an object then you have to get it with the index of it like:

```
// suppose this is the data
data = [{"foo":"bar"}, {"foo":"baz"}];
//      ^----0------^  ^-----1-----^  // indexes of the objects inside data array.
```

so these two:

```
alert(data[0].foo); // alerts bar
alert(data[0]['foo']); // alerts bar
```

here you need to have index.